# bootstrap heroku not showing

Tags: heroku, bootstrap-sass

I am using gem 'bootstrap-sass' on heroku along with gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
On my local server I can see my css changes but when I load to heroku, my custom css gets overwritten.

For instance in my local server, I can clearly see the css file in chrome developer tool as

font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

but on css this gets over written. I mean I can see the chrome developer tools that in heroku 
the above line gets strike down and another font gets shown

font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;

I have not added this font. Further the "body-background color" css color gets strike out and default white background is shown as body background color.

Can any one give any pointers.

This is how my production.rb looks like

```
Rails.application.configure do
   config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
 config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
   config.assets.compile = false
   config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
 config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://MY_CUSTOM_NAME.herokuapp.com' }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not remove scaffolding css file from stylesheets directory. That messed up css on heroku. I deleted the file and uploaded to Heroku and css worked.